# Setting wallpaper

Tags: android, wallpaper

Im trying to set my bitmap image as a wallpaper!

Im currently using this code to get it done.

```
            WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

            float minH =  wpm.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
            float minW =  wpm.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
            Log.d("seb", minH + " = Min Height");
            Log.d("seb", minW + " = Min Width");
            targetBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(targetBitmap,(int)minW, (int)minH, false);         
            wpm.setBitmap(targetBitmap);
```

It works! The phone automatically resizes the bitmap to fit the screen, but no mather how small my bitmap is, it's always cropped horizontally and scaled up.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

*(One fix would be to put a black border around and have them cropped instead of the actual picture, though Im guessing there is a better alternative )*

**EDIT**

[image: This is original picture]

this is original picture in code.

The following picture is what I mean with cropped when set to wallpaper:

[image: Cropped picture]

And this will be in the same way even if i resize the image since the system automatically enlarges the picture to fit the whole screen

Comment: Cropped horizontaly? Can you provide an example please, an cropped image can be perfect

Comment: Thank you, and in the second image, the image is croppe don the middle of the screen and the borders are white or the cropped image is filling the entire screen?

Comment: @Milos Yes, it's cropped in the middle! There is no border, currently the second image is filling the screen!